# Find Eigenvalues of multiplied Matrices when the corresponding Eigenvalues are known

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to find the eigenvalues or in particular the largest eigenvalue of a transformation which consists of two matrices:
$A = B C$.

Assuming I know the EV of both matrices $B$ and $C$, is there a general relation to the EV of $A$?

Thank you very much in advance.
Roman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. Consider 
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix},\ \ C=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then the eigenvalues of $A=BC$ are $1$ and $4$. But you change $C$ to 
$$
C=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},
$$
then the eigenvalues of $BC$ are $2,2$.

Even worse, if you take any two matrices $B',C'$ and form the block matrices
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}B'&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}, \ \ C=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&C'\end{bmatrix},
$$
then $BC=0$ no matter what the eigenvalues of $B$ and $C$ are.

Comment: I feared that and my intuition said the same. Thank you very much!